# Node js exit process event

Tags: node.js, iis

I want to catch the exit process event when IIS webservice is stopped. Tried to use SIGINT and exit events but none of them are working. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Call the process object's exit method:

`...
process.exit()`

Read more about it here https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes

Comment: Of course I used process.on('exit'... But not working